# git: push deleted branch to remote

Tags: git

**Aim : To delete a remote branch named 'branchname'**

Steps I used to do was:  **[first approach]**

1. git branch -d branchname
2. git push origin :branchname

Today I tried to delete using the same above steps, but encountered an issue as mentioned below:

```
$ git branch -d branchname
warning: deleting branch 'branchname' that has been merged to
         'refs/remotes/origin/branchname', but not yet merged to HEAD.
Deleted branch branchname (was f394ddc).
prash ~/folder/project1 (branch1)
$ git push origin branchname
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/prash/.ssh/id_rsa':
error: src refspec branchname does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@abc.xyz/projname.git'
```

Finally I was able to delete through a different approach, **[second approach]**

```
$ git push origin --delete branchname
```

Question,

Do you know why I could not delete the remote branch as per first approach ?
Also, why that warning?

**edit:**

I tried to replicate the first issue by creating and deleting a remote branch, and the only change I made this time is adding a colon before the branchname I missed out early, and it got deleted. Not sure if that was the reason earlier.

Comment: Yes, the colon in `git push origin :branchname` is important. The fact that it's so close to actually pushing the branch, `git push origin branchname`, is why the `--delete` command line flag was created.

Comment: ohh i didn't notice that , i was infact trying to push the branch and i got the error bcoz i  already deleted the branch locally. so it is always better to use the second approach. thanks.. and  do you know why i was getting the initial warning about HEAD? how does it know that i didnt merge with the HEAD? Also can you please post as answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your first example, the reason why the push failed is because you did

```
git push origin branchname
```

instead of

```
git push origin :branchname
```

The colon is significant; it's the difference between pushing a branch and deleting a branch. The one-character difference here is why `git push origin --delete branchname` is a much safer command to use, in general.

Since you had deleted `branchname`, when you tried to push it, `git` said "I don't know what `branchname` is because I don't have a branch with that name" and failed to push anything.

You might be thinking that deleting the branch locally just marked that branch as "deleted", and so when you push it, `origin`'s version of `branchname` also gets marked as "deleted", but that's not how `git` deletes branches. When you delete a branch locally, the branch is gone forever (though the commits that belonged to that branch remain, and so you can recover it by looking through `git reflog`).

---

As for the initial warning about `HEAD`, `git` is trying to ensure that you don't lose any data.

Every branch can have an "upstream" branch associated with it, so that you can use `git push` and `git pull` without having to specify an explicit remote and an explicit branch. When you delete a branch, `git` checks with the upstream branch to see if your local branch has commits that do not exist in the remote upstream branch. You will not lose any data by deleting a branch that is identical to a remote, because you can just check it out again. You can lose data if you delete a branch that contains commits that haven't been pushed upstream, so `git` tries to help you out by warning you if you delete a branch with unpushed commits.

It's just a warning though, because there are plenty of situations where you don't care about some commits. They could have been failed experiment, non-rebased versions of merged branches, or some other legitimate situation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. Well explained.